# No such column 'CaseNumber' on entity 'Name' on SocialPost Object

Tags: apex, soql, salesforce-id, socialpost

I believe this ParentId is a lookup only to Case Object (Not polymorphic)
[image: Parent Id Field[![][1]]

I even check it using /services/data/v32.0/sobjects/SocialPost/describe
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is a known issue currently with winter 19 [SocialPost Object Parent Maps to Name Entity](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000JX95QAG)

> Your query would likely never work as written, because the parent of
>   `SocialPost` can be either `Question`, `Reply` or `Case`. Error should
>   not be linked to entity 'Name'

`parentId` is the key here. Try fetching `parentId` like below as suggested in the workaround instead of `Parent.CaseNumber`

```
SELECT Name, Parentid FROM SocialPost ;
```

Comment: Salesforce /services/data/v32.0/sobjects/SocialPost/describe is misleading that is only reference to Case Object. btw Thank you!